# How to fix this problem permission denied problem on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

From last night whenever I tried to run my code on visual studio code it did not run and it shows every time
**c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file practice.exe: Permission denied**
I tried to fix this but can't fix it. How do I fix it?

Tried to run my code and expect to get an output.

Comment: Try using docker? Your code doesn't have permission to open the file. If it's starting from VSCode try running with elevated user

Comment: where is the file trying to get output _to_?

Comment: almost certainly you still have an old copy of the program running, so the exe is busy. Download sysinternals handle cli command. Use it to see who has it open